# Automatic desktop/work environment setup

Tags: nautilus, scripts, automation, workspaces

I have this strange thing I am trying to do, so before I jump into it I was curious if someone knows about existing solution or maybe have an advice as far as implementation.

I run a small software company and as it happens I often do very different type of work. When I do coding for Java project I need Eclipse running and maybe VM with something like ActiveMQ server or whatever, plus terminals to tail -F log files specific to the application, etc.
When I do something like weekly progress review with my team I need a few browser windows open and a gedit to take notes and so on.

Depending on the type of work I am doing I generally have all of the related apps open in multiple different Workspaces. So in the example above Eclipse would be open in Workspace 1, terminals would be sharing Workspace 2 and so on.

What I am trying to do is to automate opening of all these applications, positinoning them on the screen and assigning them to proper Workspaces. My current idea consists  of having a Shell script that launches specific apps depending on what type of work I am about to start doing.

Is there anything to aid this type of automation? Or is my only option is just a shell scripting at this point?

My current system is Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of Quick suggestions

autokey based on autohotkey for windows

[autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/)

or Sikuli from some people with large heads at MIT

[Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/)

Not sure whether either of these is what you are looking for but they are the easiest for automating gui related tasks in Ubuntu at the mo

Answer (score 1):

There is a little application in Ubuntu repositories designed to do exactly what you want. It is called devilspie.